# Opening images by fancybox from custom link

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, fancybox-2

I'm doing a photo gallery for my site and I wanted to have all my added photos in database. I did everything good. Database responses with the "custom link" .. I mean for example that my photo has src like `something.php?id=25` .. what I want is to open this image in fancybox (I already have fancybox installed on webpage, it shows normal-src-images well), but I'm not so good in js, etc. So I don't really know what should I do...
Basicly, the problem is that everytime I want to open the image, browser shows me image in his actual src, not in fancybox.
I did this, but It doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".selector").fancybox({
        'type' : 'image'
    });
});
</script>
```

I found this script content -- `$(".selector").fancybox({'type' : 'image'});` -- on the official web page of fancybox (they said it would help when I'm trying to open images from custom links), but It just doesn't work or I inserted it bad. I don't really know what I'm doing in js or jquery or what it is... can you guys help me with it ?

Here is a part of the source code from my gallery.php where I want fancybox to work (all scripts for fancybox are set good):

```
<div class="images"> 

<?php  
include_once('actions/db_connection.php');  
$query = "SELECT * FROM gallery"; 
$response = mysql_query($query, $connection)
if(!$response)
{
    mysql_error();
}
else
{
    while($qs = mysql_fetch_array($response))
    {
        echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="actions/download_large.php?image_ID='.$qs['image_ID'].'">
        <img class="gallery" alt="image" src="actions/download_small.php?image_ID='.$qs['image_ID'].'"></a>';
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

As I told my php "script" is showing my images good, so I think I just need some script to tell the fancybox how to open a link, but If you see something bad in code I'm opened for suggestions. Thank you so much. (Sorry for my english, hope you understand).. I'm running fancybox 2.

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==>FAQ tab, No.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({'type' : 'image'});
```

instead of

```
$(".selector").fancybox({'type' : 'image'});
```